# MarkdownSharp and invalid html

Tags: c#, markdown

I ran this piece of code

```
var m = new MarkdownSharp.Markdown();
var sz = m.Transform("Test **test** *test* boo");
Console.Write(sz);
```

and got this output. I am doing something wrong because `<ol></ol>` is not valid html. How do i get rid of it?

```
<ol>
</ol>

<p>Test <strong>test</strong> <em>test</em> boo</p>

<ol>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent revision does not have that problem.